# Solution for Wordpress Multisite subdomains on Godaddy Deluxe Cpanel Hosting

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, multisite, wildcard-subdomain

Yesterday I installed wordpress and attempted to use multisite for the first time and was unsuccessful.

Of course I added

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
```

When I began setting it up I did get a warning message along with the code for the wp-config.php file and the .htacess file.  It said something to the effect it was unable to create a subdomain, but I tried anyway.  No luck.  Then I added the following to my DNS:

```
 A  *   xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
```

When I tried again I was no longer getting an error message but I still am not getting anything for the subdomain.  I contacted godaddy and specifically asked if my account would support wordpress multisite with subdomains, they said yes, but who knows if that's true.  This page makes it sound like it doesn't:

https://uk.godaddy.com/help/enabling-wordpress-multisites-6143

So I would appreciate any help in figuring out when I'm doing wrong, even if that help is letting me know that's it's not possible on my plan.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

create an actual subdomain using *.yourdomain.com for whatever domain your working with